# How to read tables from a location and write data to a table of other cluster

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql

I read table statistics from a metastore starting spark application setting up hive.metastore.uris. However I need write data to another hive.

I've tryed to clean Active and Default Session, build another session with the new metastore uri, but spark continues trying write to the table of the first hive.

```scala
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
          .appName(appName)
          .enableHiveSupport()
          .config("hive.metastore.uris", FIRST_METASTORE)
          .config("spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreOrc", "false")
          .config("spark.sql.caseSensitive", "false")
          .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")
          .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
          .getOrCreate()

val df = spark.sql("DESCRIBE FORMATTED source_table")

SparkSession.clearActiveSession()
SparkSession.clearDefaultSession()

val spark2 = SparkSession.builder()
          .appName(appName)
          .enableHiveSupport()
          .config("hive.metastore.uris", NEW_MESTASTORE)
          .config("spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreOrc", "false")
          .config("spark.sql.caseSensitive", "false")
          .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")
          .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
          .getOrCreate()

SparkSession.setDefaultSession(sparkSession2)
SparkSession.setActiveSession(sparkSession2)

df.write
      .format("parquet")
      .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
      .insertInto("other_cluster_table")
  }
```

As I said, it would be expected that dataframe should be wrote to the table location of the new metastore and catalog, but it doesn't. This happens because interface DataFrameWriter get information from [`df.sparkSession.sessionState.sqlParser.parseTableIdentifier(tableName)`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.scala) in order to insert into some existent table, but how could I deal with it?

Comment: Spark does not read or write _data_ "to a Metastore". It reads/writes to HDFS. And it can read on cluster A then write to cluster B _(requires some extra params with Kerberos, but it's supported)_. So your best bet is to **hard-code** the schema/location of the source table, read it directly from source HDFS without any Hive integration, then write to your target table w/ Metastore integration.

Comment: Thanks Samson. When I said "to a metastore" I mean that Spark is writing to the table with location based on the metastore which I started app and not the location of the "new" session. I'm getting table statistics with "describe formatted" statement that collect information from metastore. Because of this, read table directly does not work. I try to correcto myself editing the question. Thanks

Comment: By the way, passing Hadoop properties directy to the Spark configuration does not work, because they are not Spark properties, hence they are ignored. You must prepend them with `spark.hadoop.` to have Spark forward them to its Hadoop client libs.

Comment: I.e. try `.config("spark.hadoop.hive.metastore.uris", NEW_MESTASTORE)` `.config("spark.hadoop.hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")` etc.

Comment: Just look at the source code, function `appendSparkHadoopConfigs` in  https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.3/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/SparkHadoopUtil.scala

Comment: Thanks Samson. The location of the table comes from metastore and not from hadoop configs

Comment: Hive uses the Hadoop code base. The Hive `Configuration` class inherts from Hadoop `Configuration` class. Spark uses the Hive Java client, and the Java HDFS client, and the Java YARN client. Spark injects the same properties into Hive `Configuration` and Hadoop `Configuration`. Just. Try.

Comment: Hi Sanson, I tried to add new metastore configuration to hadoop properties, but without success. Then I adopted a solution more simple than try to work distinct sparksessions. I wrote the parquet directly to the partition directory and then add the partition with beeline. What do you think? By the way, thank by explain about hadoop configs.

Answer (score 0):

After reading about multiple [sparkContexts](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2243), I solve this question just writing the parquet directly to namenode/directory/to/partition/ and then adding partition to table using beeline.